# Polymer 1.0 - routing

Tags: polymer

I'm new to Polymer. I start writing a simple webapp in which
1. User first land in a login page
2. If user passes login, then direct user to content page

I write an element "login"

```
<dom-module id="login">
  <template>
    <!-- local DOM for your element -->
    <p>Username</p>
    <input class="paper-font-body2" value="{{email::change}}" type="email">
    <br/>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input class="paper-font-body2" value="{{password::change}}" type="password">
    <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>

    <iron-ajax
      id="ajax"
      url=""
      method="POST"
      on-response="signInResponse"
      debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>

    <button on-click="signIn">Signin</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  // element registration
  Polymer({
    is: "login",

    // add properties and methods on the element's prototype
    properties: {
      // declare properties for the element's public API
      email: {
        type: String,
        value: "username"
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        value: "password"
      },
      errorMessage: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      }
    },

    signIn: function() {
      this.$.ajax.url = "http://myserver/login/email";
      this.$.ajax.params = {"email":this.email, "password": this.password};
      this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    },

    signInResponse: function(request) {
      response = request.detail.response;
      console.log(response);
      if (response.code == '0') {
        this.fire("signin-success", response);
      } else {
        this.fire("signin-fail", response);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

On index.html (main page), I use

```
<self-login
      sign-in-success="onSignedIn"
      ></self-login>
```

Question: in the onSignedIn() callback, I would route my page to /content. How can I do?

EDIT 1: As @zacharytamas suggest, I try to use app-router as following

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>app-router</title>
  <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" shim-shadowdom>
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>
<app-router>
  <app-route path="/" import="/elements/home-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/test" import="/elements/home-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="*" import="/elements/not-found-page.html"></app-route>
</app-router>

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

home-page.html

```
<dom-module  id="home-page" noscript>
  <template>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

It shows a blank page when I browse to both http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:3000/test on Chrome. Any idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Polymer does not have routing built into it by default. There are several front-end routing frameworks you can use with Polymer, however.

A very commonly used approach is a custom element called [app-router](https://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/), which lets you define routes declaratively with just HTML alone. I've had some success with it before. Check out [the website](https://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/)for information on setting it up.

Another HTML-based way of doing it is a custom element made by a member of the Polymer team called [more-routing](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing). Google has a video series about Polymer called [Polycasts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN) which [made a video explaining the `more-routing` approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-67kb7poIT8). You should check that video out for info about getting started.

Another option is to do it with JavaScript using the [page.js framework](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/). This is the method used the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en). [Here's another Polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDQqP5Yyczg) to get you started on that way.

Welcome to the Polymer world!

Comment: It seems that app-rooter not yet supports Polymer 1.0

Comment: Hmm. I used it with Polymer 0.9 last week and the API between 0.9 and 1.0 is very similar. Do you get an error or does it just not work?

Comment: Yes, I've issue with app-router. See my EDIT on the question

Comment: I wrote dna-router, inspired by Angluar's UI-router, that works with Polymer^1.0. It lets you declare routes in HTML and also it is much user friendly.
https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router/

Comment: Looks like a router is on the roadmap for 2016 from polymer team. https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2016/02/16/2016-roadmap/

Comment: Good news! the Polymer team has released an official router. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing Please upvote my new answer below :D

Answer (score 8):

Good news! The Polymer team has released an official router. An excellent introduction is available on their blog:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing

And the Readme.md on the Github repo is quite instructive:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route

There are two elements necessary for basic functionality, `<app-location>` and `<app-route>`

The following is a simple example:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="[[route]]"
    pattern="/users"
    active="{{usersRouteIsActive}}">
</app-route>
```

In the above example `usersRouteIsActive` will receive a boolean value, `true` if the route matches `/users`, and false if it does not. Simple, right? After this, as your application's routes get more complicated the app-route element has more features that will support those needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'dna-router'. Its relatively new and supports Polymer-1.0.
You can create routing purely in html.

Dna-router also supports user-authentication. You can pass login status and loggedin data in its 'dna-config' element. Router will show page based on login status. 
You can declare which states need user authentication.

Its still under development and have some glitches in it. But worth giving a try.

Github: https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router/

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the kind of router you use. I was unhappy with the state of Polymer routers, so I wrote [excess-router](https://github.com/atotic/excess-router). With this router, you would:

- define your routes, and make `/content` is a default route
- configure router to be started manually
- start the router manually on signin

```html
<excess-router-config manual-start></excess-router-config>
<excess-route route="/content"></excess-route>
<excess-route route="/(.*)" redirect-to="/content" activation-modifiers="x"></excess-route>

<script>
  function onSignedIn() {
    Excess.RouteManager.start();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have not played too much, but it seems to actually work with 1.0, which is better than any of the options touted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solving this problem just adding in page template this code:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'home-page'
    });
</script>
```

Full page code:

```
<link href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<dom-module id="home-page">
   <template>
      <div>Home page</div>
   </template>

   <script>
      Polymer({
         is: 'home-page'
      });
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Polymer 1.4, carbon-route (later renamed app-route) can be used:

- https://github.com/polymerelements/carbon-route
- https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2016/03/28/carbon-route-released/
- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/routing.html

Here's an example taken from the polymer blog:

```
<carbon-location route="{{route}}">
</carbon-location>

<carbon-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/tabs/:tabName" data="{{data}}">
</carbon-route>

<paper-tabs selected="{{data.tabName}}" attr-for-selected="key">
  <paper-tab key="foo">Foo</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab key="bar">Bar</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab key="baz">Baz!</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<neon-animated-pages selected="{{data.tabName}}"
                     attr-for-selected="key"
                     entry-animation="slide-from-left-animation"
                     exit-animation="slide-right-animation">
  <neon-animatable key="foo">Foo Page Here</neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable key="bar">Bar Page Goes Here</neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable key="baz">Baz Page, the Best One of the Three</neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

See also similar question: [Routing in polymer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834253/routing-in-polymer-1-0)