# How to use app-route in polymer 2 to have deep paths?

Tags: polymer

This is part of polymer application starter kit code. I just added a `my-news-list.html` to elements in src:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer">
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="news" href="/news">News</a>
      <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header slot="header" condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-news-list name="news" route="{{subroute}}"></my-news-list>
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
    </iron-pages>

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Everything is OK, `<my-news-list>` and `<my-view1>` loads correctly when click on theme in `<iron-selector>`. in `<my-news-list>` element I got list of all news with `<iron-ajax>` and it works fine:

```
<iron-ajax auto url="localhost/api/news/news" handle-as="json" last-response="{{newsList}}"></iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{newsList}}">
    <a href="/news/[[item.id]]">[[item.title]]</a>
</template>
```

I have a other element for viewing single news content, named `<my-news-view>` that I want to load it when click on title of each news in `<my-news-list>`. On click path changes to: localhost:8081:/news/2 correctly but `<my-news-list>` element loads again Instead of `<my-news-view>`.

I don't paste other elements codes(bindings, ...).

Now I want to know how config `<app-route>` and use subroute to have load elements in this paths:

```
// For News
/news                     //all news list. loads my-news-list element
/news/12                  //news[12] view. loads my-news-view elemnt
/news/categories          //all categories list view. loads my-news-categories element
/news/categories/3        //category[3] news list view. loads my-news-category element

// and jobs similar to module
/Jobs
/jobs/country/cityName
/jobs/country/cityName/featured
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include some details. What version of polymer are you running? What have you done so far to configure your routes?

Answer (score 2):

You should declare you "my-news-view" component in "iron-pages" just like you do:

```
 <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name"
    fallback-selection="view404" role="main">
  <my-news-view name="news-view" route="{{subroute}}" />
</iron-pages>
```

So iron-pages would know what component to show when user navigate to /news-view/12 based on **name attribute** not component name itself.

BUT. There are some tricky parts on your solution:

1. Note how you pass subroute to child components to decouple it internal 
   routing mechanism from actual url path where it resides.
2. Starter kit uses lazy-loading to import components and inside that function it adds prefix 'my-' to actual route 'news-view'. So that is how result component name to load become 'my-news-view'. That may confuse.

You could read more about this [polymer shop case study](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/case-study#routing).

PS: personally I think that the way the polymers sample app routing works confused a lot because it looks like web-server static name resolution (based on component name, and not components attribute 'name') but it don't.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the  component inside the  component and then use the sub route to know the id for

Answer (score 0):

Try `dna-router`. It is now compatible with Polymer 2.0 project.

Please follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31236817/5069120

Or visit https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router